# Куда бы спрятать данные..

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Добрый день.
Имею такую ситуацию:
Есть елемент (блок), при клике на него первый раз, аяксом достаются кое-какие данные и записываются в data-it атрибут этого елемента. По второму клику на элемент - эти данные показываются пользователю.

Проблема в чем: нужно чтобы пользователь не знал, что там за данные хранятся ПОСЛЕ ПЕРВОГО клика, а узнавал только после второго. "Продвинутый" юзер может ведь и исходники просматривать.

Так вот вопрос - куда бы можно было прятать данные в этом промежутке между первым и вторым кликом? Думал просто создать гдето в дебрях фетура элемент и всё ложить в его атрибуты, но ведь со временем заметят...

p.s. вытаскивать данные аяксом при втором клике - не вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные в таком случае никак не спрятать, "продвинутый" юзер всегда их найдет, если ему будет нужно, например, открыв firebug и посмотреть что вернет ajax-запрос. Если данные нужно прятать, то только шифрованием, но лучше через сервак, т.е. ajax-запрос отсылается на свой сервак, он дергает что-то извне(например), сохраняет у себя на серваке. А при втором клике эти данные получаешь уже со своего сервака.
Ну а так, если делать псевдо, то как варианты:

```
// 1
$.jStorage

// 2
var dataAjax = [];
dataAjax.push(data);

// 3
$('<div id="tempStorage"></div>').html(data);
```

Comment: через сервак - работающая тема, но это у меня будет уже слишком много обращений к серверу.. а что вы говорили насчет шифрования?  
допустим при первом клике вытаскиваются данные(это цыфра будут) в уже зашифрованном виде и пускай запишутся в атрибут этого же тега (как у меня сейчас) а при втором уже расшифровывать и выводить. Можно такое сделать? Какие шифровальщики для этого подойдут?

Comment: Любые, например, aes.
Шифрование по ключу. Только вся фишка в том, что нужно будет хранить этот ключ на клиенте, а это палевное занятие, даже есть абфускатором пройтись. Так что тут остается только вопрос сервака, это 100% вариант. На серваке храните данные и дергаете аяксом второй раз. Что значит много запросов? Если запросов от одного юзера больше, чем 10 в секунду, то юзайте web sockets (ну или flash sockets для старых браузеров). Открываете сокет и гоняете инфу, пока клиент не закроет страницу. А если обращений меньше 10, то не парьтесь, правильно настроенный сервак выдержит 1к клиентов.

Comment: Смотря, конечно, какой. Если вопрос безопастности, то решайте на стороне сервака, другого выхода нет и не будет :)

Comment: Вообще надеюсь что в проекте который я пишут будет намного больше чем 1к, так что заранее думаю об оптимизации )  Про сокеты спасибо, на выходных сяду разбираться.

Comment: Md5 + salt

Answer (score 2):

Можно строить этот блок по второму клику. Построить можно, используя JS-функцию

```
<input type="button" value "ClickMe" id="ClickMe">//кнопка
<script language="javascript">
    $("#ClickMe").toggle(click1, click2); // заюзаем jQuery
    function click1() {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = text; // значение переменной text можно хранить в другом файле,   который надо будет подключить( тогда вряд ли кто найдет значение переменной )
        ...
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    function click2() {
        document.body.removeChild(div);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: и подключать append'ом?  
ну как вариант, спасибо :)
  
хотя еще подожду, может у кого-еще какая-то идейка будет.

Comment: Ну вам по-любому придется данные выводить динамически, потому что, если вы их выведите на стадии прогрузки страницы, то из смогут прочитать.

Answer (score 1):

Просто завести глобальный массив и складывать в него данные?

Comment: глобальный массив в js - это достояние всего народа, который заходит на сайт=)

Comment: я вот тоже подумал насчет простого массива, уже даже начал писать. а потом задумался, а может ли "еще более" продвинутый юзер прочитать содержимое массива?  
  
а всё.. вопрос отпадает, забыл про файрбаг) буду думать насчет шифрования

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/data/
Вот ваше решение, таже дата, только в объекте самого елемента, без атрибута.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас будем разбираться :)